# WSO2 APIM Token Exchange

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I need to perform the token-exchange process between apis calls passing through WSO2 APIM, something like the scenario below:

```
User -> client app -> WSO2 APIM -> JWT Sent to -> Microservice 1
```

Next, Microservice 1 needs to propagate the authenticated user's JWT to another service that it depends on (Microservice 2),:

```
Microservice 1 -> JWT Token Exchange (token issued on the first client access to microservice 1 api) 
-> WSO2 APIM -> JWT Sent to -> Microservice 2
```

It is not enough to propagate the JWT to APIM, Microservice 1 needs to issue a new access token to consume the microservice 2 API, and it is precisely in this process that the token-exchange fits.

Reading the WSO2 APIM All in One documentation, I didn't see anything related to the token exchange process, I only saw about the JWT Bearer, but I don't know if it contemplates this scenario that I reported above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the JWT that you send when invoking an API resource, you can enable it by adding the following configuration in `deployment.toml` file resides in `<APIM-Home>/repository/conf directory`.

```
[apim.oauth_config]
  enable_outbound_auth_header = true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @vithursa! The JWT generation is set up and being sent to the API backend, however what need is exactly to propagate this JWT to other internal microservices, and these microservices are behind the API Gateway, I can't talk to them directly. Another detail, each microservice has its own basic token (client id and secret), so I would need a token exchange from the JWT that received in the first backend to be able to issue a new access token on behalf of the authenticated user (JWT issued).

PS .: I edited the question above to detail the scenario.

Comment: I assume MicroService 1 returns a token that is required to invoke MicroService 2. Is this a correct assumption? Are both MicroService1 and MicroService2 services deployed in WSO2 APIM?

Comment: So, both apis of microservice 1 and 2, are implanted in the same APIM. Currently this WSO2 works with opaque access token. The access token used to consume ms1 was using this opaque AT, and a JWT arrives on its backend. However, for ms1 to consume ms2 it needs another access token, however I only have the JWT. So I say to use the token exchange to propagate this authentication, from the JWT issue a new access token. In fact, I need to know if this is possible. Suddenly, I will need to stop using the opaque token at the border and always work with JWT from end to end.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the context path of the other microservice 2 in audience field of the Jwt and pass the request header's from microservice 1 to microservice 2 and then it will work